# How to update a database table letting two fields be empty/not filled/null

Tags: sql, database, sql-update

On a blog I'm coding I want admins to be able to edit a comment. This works just fine, but there's a problem with writing a new comment because of two fields in the table that should be empty then.

The Db-table `comments` is build up like this:

`comments(id, content, post_id, comment_author, date, editedBy, editedAt)`

When a new comment is written the fields `editedBy` and `editedAt` should be empty/just not filled/null, since it hasn't been updated obviously.

**I can't just leave the fields empty, can I put an empty string in them or mark them as `NULL`?**

```
public function insertForPost($content, $post_id, $comment_author, $date, $editedBy, $editedAt)
{
  $table = $this->getTableName();

  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO `{$table}`(`content`, `post_id`, `comment_author`, `date`,
    `editedBy`, `editedAt`) VALUES (:content, :post_id, :comment_author, :date,
    :editedBy, :editedAt)"
  );

  $stmt->execute([
    'content' => $content,
    'post_id' => $post_id,
    'comment_author' => $comment_author,
    'date' => $date,
    'editedBy' => $editedBy,
    'editedAt' => $editedAt
  ]);
}
```

All parameters have the right data in them, I just don't know what to do with `editedBy` and `editedAt`.

When the comment gets edited(which works just fine) `editedBy` will be filled with the username of the one editing the comment and `editedAt` will be filled with the date when the comment has been edited, so both are Strings.

**I want to know if I need to put an empty string in these two fields or set them `null` and how to do it.**

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as `editedAt` and `editedBy` are nullable (so the columns don't include a `NOT NULL` statement during the creation of the table), you can leave them from the set of columns inbetween the tablename and the `VALUES` clause with an insert or update statement. Hence, the query results in:

`` INSERT INTO `{$table}`(`content`, `post_id`, `comment_author`, `date`) VALUES (:content, :post_id, :comment_author, :date); ``

Comment: Thank you, it kind of worked, I just can't seem to find the comments in the database but they're still shown on the post-site and the site gets the values from the database? :D

Comment: ah, nevermind. It just didn't show me every comment :)

Answer (score 1):

On the database:

```
alter table alter <column_name> set default <default_value>;
```

assuming you're on mysql/mariadb so for each new comment you have the fields with default value.

This code will update the data already in the db with the new value.

```
update <table_name> set <column_name> = <default_value> where <column_name> is null
```

just insert the column name you need